# Oracle Sequence Trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sequence

I am not too familiar with Oracle but I have written a trigger for my application to generate numbering for records using a sequence. The problem I have is, the numbers may already be in use and I want to add a check to ensure if the number is already used, to select the next one available from the sequence. Can this be done firstly and if so, any assistance would be really appreciated?

```
DROP TRIGGER COMPLAIN_TRG_ENQUIRYNO;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER COMPLAIN_TRG_ENQUIRYNO
BEFORE INSERT
ON COMPLAIN REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_enquiry_no_end    complain.enquiry_no_end%TYPE;
BEGIN    
    SELECT seq_enquiryno.NEXTVAL INTO l_enquiry_no_end FROM   dual;  
    IF :NEW.ENQUIRY_NO_END = ' ' THEN
        :NEW.ENQUIRY_NO_END := l_enquiry_no_end;
    END IF;     
EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END ;
```

Comment: You shouldn't really mix auto-assigned IDs from a sequence with manually assigned IDs. If you have existing records that were manually assigned and want to start auto-assigning for all new records, you can start the sequence higher than all existing values, so there will be no overlap. (You also shouldn't catch an exception unless you plan to handle it; just re-raising it hides the original location of the problem).

Comment: Thanks for the reply & help Alex! The numbers are not being used as an ID just as a customer reference number. Would you still recommend not to mix and to start at a higher number range?

Comment: If you mix then both the manual and automatic setting will have to handle clashes. It's simpler to have only one mechanism.

Comment: I would start at the higher range, but also try to ensure that there won't be any more manually-entered numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a sequence if you have existing (numeric) data in the column as this can lead to duplicates. Either start from empty and use a sequence or if you are really stuck find the maximum pk you have and reset the startswith property of the sequence.

Alternatively you could use guids instead of guids which have the advantage of always being globally unique - call the sys_guid() function in your trigger. They can lead to other issues with indexing etc though.